# ¿Como llamar el resultado de una funcion desde una clase en Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, condiciones

Quisiera saber como llamar el resultado de una funcion que esta en otra clase, en Visual Basic .Net, para luego utilizar ese resultado para comparacion en un if?

Deseo llamar el resultado de la funcion RestaBalance, en especifico, del if que hay en ella, quisiera tenerlo en la clase desde donde quiero llamarla.

Estoy simulando un cajero automatico. El Formulario FRM_RetireEfectivo2 llama dos formularios. Uno es para la impresion del recibo luego de que se introduce la cantidad deseada a retirar y el otro es para el mismo procedimiento pero sin recibo con fin de retirar el dinero al final. En caso contrario, el programa lanza el Mensaje: "Fondos Insuficientes." Cuando llamo a la funcion de esta manera: oConexion.RestaBalance(FRM_InserteIDTarjeta.TXB_IDTarjeta.Text), se evalua la funcion RestaBalance, cuando el fondo es insuficiente, arroja el mensaje pero tambien llama a los formularios previamente mencionados. Desearia que cuando arroje el mensaje: "Fondos Insuficientes", no llame esos formularios.

Gracias anticipadas.

---

Formulario desde donde deseo llamar el resultado de la Funcion RestaBalance:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FRM_RetiroEfectivo2

    Dim oConexion As New clsConexionDB


    Private Sub BTN_Aceptar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_Aceptar.Click


        If TXB_MontoARetirar.Text.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Debe llenar el campo.")
            Return
        End If
        If TXB_MontoARetirar.Text = "0" Then
            MsgBox("Introduzca el monto a retirar.")
            Return
        End If
        Dim intMonto As Integer
        If Not Integer.TryParse(TXB_MontoARetirar.Text, intMonto) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor introduzca un valor en el campo.")
            Return
        End If
        Select Case intMonto
            Case > 10000
                MsgBox("Solo es posible retirar hasta RD$10000.00 en los cajeros.")
                Return

        End Select

        Dim NumMultiplo1 = intMonto Mod 100
        Dim NumMultiplo2 = intMonto Mod 200
        Dim NumMultiplo3 = intMonto Mod 500
        Dim NumMultiplo4 = intMonto Mod 1000
        Dim NumMultiplo5 = intMonto Mod 2000


        oConexion.RestaBalance(FRM_InserteIDTarjeta.TXB_IDTarjeta.Text)




        If NumMultiplo1 = 0 OrElse NumMultiplo2 = 0 OrElse NumMultiplo3 = 0 OrElse NumMultiplo4 = 0 OrElse NumMultiplo5 = 0 Then
                Dim Respuesta = MessageBox.Show("Desea imprimir un recibo?", "Imprimir Recibo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                If Respuesta = DialogResult.Yes Then

                    FRM_RetireSuTarjeta.Show()
                    Me.Hide()

                Else

                    FRM_RetireSuTarjeta1.Show()
                    Me.Hide()

                End If

            Else
                MsgBox("Solo se pueden realizar retiros en multiplos de billetes de RD$100.00, RD$200.00, RD$500.00, RD$1000.00 y RD$2000.00 pesos.")
            End If


    End Sub
End Class
```

clsConexionDB:

```
Public Class clsConexionDB

    Private _strUserDB As String
    Private _strPassDB As String
    Private _strNombreDB As String
    Private _strSRVNombre As String
    Private _strConexion As String

    Private adAdaptador As SqlDataAdapter
    Private tbTabla As DataTable
    Private drRegistros As SqlDataReader

    Public strComando As String

    Public _Error As Boolean
    Public _Mensaje As String


    Public Sub New()

        With ATMApp3.My.Settings
            _strSRVNombre = .strNameSRV.ToString
            _strNombreDB = .strNameDB.ToString
            _strUserDB = .strUserDB
            _strPassDB = .strPassUserDB
        End With

        _strConexion = "Data Source=JOVALLES-PC\SQLSERVEREX;Initial Catalog=" & _strNombreDB & ";User ID=" & _strUserDB & ";Password=" & _strPassDB

        Try
            Dim dbConexion As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_strConexion)
            dbConexion.Open()
            MsgBox("CONECTADO")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error al conectarse debido a: " + ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub


Public Function Modificar(ByVal pTarjeta As String, ByVal pBalance As Integer) As String

        Dim Salida As String = "Se modifico correctamente."
        Dim dbConexion As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_strConexion)
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("up_modificar_balance", dbConexion)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Try

            If dbConexion.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                dbConexion.Open()
            End If

            With cmd.Parameters

                .AddWithValue("@Numero_Tarjeta", pTarjeta)
                .AddWithValue("@Balance", pBalance)

            End With

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception

            Salida = "No se modifico debido a:" + ex.ToString
            dbConexion.Close()
        End Try

        Return Salida


    End Function


 Public Function RestaBalance(ByVal pTarjeta As String) As SqlDataReader

        Dim dbConexion As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_strConexion)
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("up_consultar_balance", dbConexion)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        With cmd.Parameters

            .AddWithValue("@Numero_Tarjeta", pTarjeta)

        End With


        Try

            If dbConexion.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                dbConexion.Open()
            End If

            drRegistros = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If drRegistros.Read Then

                Dim Resta As Double
                Dim BalanceActual As Double = CStr(drRegistros("BALANCE_DISPONIBLE"))
                Resta = (BalanceActual - FRM_RetiroEfectivo2.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text)


                If BalanceActual < FRM_RetiroEfectivo2.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text Then
                      MsgBox("Fondos Insuficientes.")

                Else

                    Modificar(FRM_InserteIDTarjeta.TXB_IDTarjeta.Text, Resta)

                End If


            Else

                _Error = True
                _Mensaje = "No hay datos"
                dbConexion.Close()
                Return Nothing

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("No se modifico debido a:" + ex.ToString)
            dbConexion.Close()
        End Try

    End Function
End Class
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola estimado, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: La solucion mas senciila es que `RestaBalance` devuelva un valor indicando el resultado de la operacion. Actualmente la funcion se supone que devuelve un `SqlDataReader`, aunque no se para que dado que no devuelves nada.

Comment: Ok. ¿Se podria crear una variable tipo entero, igualarla a un numero y alojarla en el lugar donde arroja el mensaje: "Fondos Insuficientes" y tomar esa variable como valor?

Comment: Efectivamente Jesus. Crea una variable de tipo entero que empiece en 0 (que indicaria que el resultado de la funcion es correcto), luego en cada error (por ejemplo, balance insuficiente) lo modificas (por ejemplo 1- balance insuficiente, -1 no hay datos...) y haces return de esa variable. Luego la lees desde donde llamas a la funcion y dependiendo del valor, actúas de una manera u otra.

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrarme un ejemplo por favor?

Comment: Te he añadido una respuesta. No es muy dificil como verás (es posible que haya algun error dado que lo he hecho de cabeza y no estoy muy acostumbrado a vb)

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no usas valor de retorno en tu función, lo que yo haría sería crear una variable de tipo entero que empiece en 0 (que indicaría que el resultado de la función es correcto), luego en cada error (por ejemplo, balance insuficiente) lo modificas (por ejemplo 1- balance insuficiente, -1 no hay datos...) y retornamos esa variable:

```
Public Function RestaBalance(ByVal pTarjeta As String) As Integer
    Dim resultado As Integer = 0
    Dim dbConexion As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_strConexion)
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("up_consultar_balance", dbConexion)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    With cmd.Parameters

        .AddWithValue("@Numero_Tarjeta", pTarjeta)

    End With


    Try

        If dbConexion.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            dbConexion.Open()
        End If

        drRegistros = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If drRegistros.Read Then

            Dim Resta As Double
            Dim BalanceActual As Double = CStr(drRegistros("BALANCE_DISPONIBLE"))
            Resta = (BalanceActual - FRM_RetiroEfectivo2.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text)


            If BalanceActual < FRM_RetiroEfectivo2.TXB_MontoARetirar.Text Then
                  MsgBox("Fondos Insuficientes.")
                  resultado=1
            Else
                Modificar(FRM_InserteIDTarjeta.TXB_IDTarjeta.Text, Resta)
            End If


        Else
            resultado=-1
            _Error = True
            _Mensaje = "No hay datos"
            dbConexion.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        resultado=-1 
        MsgBox("No se modifico debido a:" + ex.ToString)
        dbConexion.Close()
    End Try
    Return resultado
End Function
```

Como ves, durante la función modifico `resultado` dependiendo de los errores que haya, y al final de la funcion lo retorno. Entonces, al llamar a la función sólo hay que comprobar este valor:

```
...
Dim resultadoRestar as Integer
resultadoRestar = oConexion.RestaBalance(FRM_InserteIDTarjeta.TXB_IDTarjeta.Text)
Select Case resultadoRestar 
Case 0
    MsgBox("Resta Correcta")
Case 1
    MsgBox("Fondos Insuficientes")
Case -1
    MsgBox("Se produjo un error o no hay datos");
End Select
```